# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps Polyline points

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps and  https://github.com/nuitsjp/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Bindings (for binding polyline) libraries for map in my project. I have polyline with 99000 positions. This polyline don't put to the map. And I don't have an error. Has the maximum count positions polyline? Maybe there is a way around this?

```
    ObservableCollection<Polyline> Polylines = new ObservableCollection<Polyline>();
            
    Polyline polyline = new Polyline()
    {
      Tag = tag,
      StrokeWidth = strokeWidth,
      StrokeColor = strokeColor,
      ZIndex = zIndex
    };
            
    foreach(var position in positions)
    {
      polyline.Positions.Add(position);
    }
        
    Polylines.Add(polyline);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller subset of data?

Comment: Check output and debug windows upon running your project in VS, probably there are some messages and silent exceptions displayed. Also, allow in Debug-Exception settings all exception and run your app. Probably you'll get some visible exception upon running.

Comment: I would guess 99k points probably requires too many resources.  I would try to simplify the data so it has a more reasonable number of points

Comment: @fafael, in output  window window does not contain messages and errors

Comment: @jason, It works on IOS.. Magic...